# How to bind Xamarin.Forms XAML StaticResource Key dynamically?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Is it possible to dynamically bind the `Key` of a `StaticResource` in `Xamarin.Forms` `XAML`?

I am trying to build a `Shell` Flyout menu and would like to use Font Icons

Here is the Item Template

```
<Shell.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ContentView>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="{StaticResource *key={Binding Icon}*}"></Label>
                <Label Text="{Binding Title}"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentView>
    </DataTemplate>
</Shell.ItemTemplate>
```

The menu items are created using

```
<FlyoutItem Title="HOME" FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
    <ShellContent Title="Categories &amp; Cards" Icon="fa-th-large">

    </ShellContent>
    <ShellContent Title="To-Dos" Icon="fa-tasks">

    </ShellContent>
</FlyoutItem>
```

I am trying to avoid creating a converter

I am using the technique outlined here
https://montemagno.com/xamarin-forms-custom-fonts-everywhere/

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know your settings but for me you'll do better to go with the Dynamic Ressoures.

The resource:

```
<x:String x:Key="Icon">&#xf0f4;</x:String>
```

The Xaml:

```
 <Label Text="{DynamicResource Icon}"></Label>
```

And then in the ViewModel, you can play with the change of the text.

```
App.Current.Resources["Icon"] = YourNewValueHere;
```

Comment: Clever. Will this work for all the Shell Flyout items? The template is supposed to replace each flyout with a different icon which why I was looking to dynamically bind the key for the static resource.

Comment: I test it with above code. I put the ` <x:String x:Key="Icon">monkey.png</x:String>` in ` <Shell.Resources>` Then used it in the `ShellContent` of `FlyoutItem`, it worked.