# Setting FontImageSource Glyph dynamically in .NET MAUI app

Tags: maui

In my .NET MAUI app, I have a whole bunch of glyph icons defined in an `Icons.xaml` file and I can use them like this:

```
<Image>
  <Image.Source>
     <FontImageSource
        FontFamily="MYGLIYPHS"
        Glyph="{StaticResource MyIconName}"
        Color="{StaticResource DarkGray}"
        Size="35" />
  </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Now, I want to be able to set this programmatically in my view model -- possibly using an `ObservableProperty`. So, the idea is to set the icon name to `IconX` initially but then when a certain condition is met in my view model code, I want to change it to `IconY`. How can I do this?

Using a simple text property didn't work because I need to set the name of the icon but also indicate that it's a `StaticResource`. So, the following didn't work:

View model code:

```
...
[ObservableProperty]
string iconName;
```

View code:

```
<Image>
  <Image.Source>
     <FontImageSource
        FontFamily="MYGLIYPHS"
        Glyph="{Binding IconName}"
        Color="{StaticResource DarkGray}"
        Size="35" />
  </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

I thought about setting the `Glyph` name as a `DynamicResource` but couldn't get that to work yet either. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bind Xamarin.Forms XAML StaticResource Key dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61977397/how-to-bind-xamarin-forms-xaml-staticresource-key-dynamically)

Comment: How do you use DynamicResource? Here is the document for it :[Dynamic styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/styles/xaml#dynamic-styles).